# How do I store the ID and email into a database?

Tags: database, facebook

I keep trolling the internet for tutorials on how to do this to no avail. I followed [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/)
on getting it set up, but it doesn't go through how to save the information received. Actually it doesn't go through if there *is* and information received.

Thanks so much!!

more information.
What I want to do is have a FB login to my site. If it is a fist time user, I want his ID, name, and email saved to a database. If it's an old user, then I need his ID to check it against the database.

heres my current code:

```
 <html>
<head>
  <title>My Facebook Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : '223157403572264',
        status     : true, 
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true,
        oauth      : true,
      });
    };
    (function(d){
       var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
       d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
     }(document));
  </script>
  <div class="fb-login-button" data-scope="email,user_checkins">
    Login with Facebook
  </div>
</body>
```

edit- more information

edit2- my code

Comment: You will need to post more information about what you are trying to do specifically and code samples for people to help you. :(

Comment: thanks RSG! I added more info =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just after the `init` of your Facebook object, you can "subscribe" to events, like saying "when my user is just logged in, i want to do that..."
For further informations about that, you can look to [this topic](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8665809/fb-login-dont-know-how-to-get-response-after-a-successful-login/8665984#8665984) !

But what you really need is, i think, to use the `FB.api` to call for specific informations about the user. Once he's logged in you can call this function like this :

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  alert(response.name);
});
```

You make a call to retrieve information about `/me` (= the current logged in user), then you have your callback function which you can use to send your data with an AJAX call or anything else to some server script that will store it to your Database, but you know how to do this part I think :)

For more informations sabout the `FB.api` your should check [this documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/)

Comment: That was an awesome response, and I sincerely thank you for it. May your life be as fruitful as that answer made mine. Peace be unto the world in your honor, because god knows, you deserve it.

Comment: Thanks man, i'll just add one thing : To check if your user is logged in on each page you have a FB.getLoginStatus() which gives you a particular response if the user is logged in. You should give a look [at this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) :)

Comment: @Flow'S.: How to pass the value for email to server side, am using asp.net

Answer (score 1):

If you receive the users data via javascript you could send a request to your own scripts via jQuery's post function. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ 
If you dont use jQuery the idea would be the same. Just us JS to send a POST Request to your own site/script and save that data in your database. See this for example: http://javascript.about.com/library/blajax01.htm - http://javascript.about.com/library/blajax02.htm

Or is your question like "how to store data in your own Database?"

Comment: My question is simpler then that. the question is HOW to receive data at all.